# Longest Increasing SubSequence using Binary Search

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to implement The Longest Increasing SubSequence using Binary Search. Well I have coded the algorithm and my test cases are getting satisfied but when I submit the code,it is failing for some test cases like for example for the following list,

29471 5242 21175 28931 2889 7275 19159 21773 1325 6901, the answer should be 4 but I am getting 5.Below is my code,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LongestIncreasingSubSequence {

    public static int BS(int[] arr,int low,int high,int key){

        int mid;

        while ((high - low) > 1) {

            mid = (int) Math.ceil((low + high) / 2);

            if (arr[mid] >= key) {
                high = mid;
            } else {
                low = mid;
            }
        }
        return high;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        n = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        int LS[] = new int[arr.length];
        int count = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        LS[0] = arr[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < LS[0]) {
                LS[0] = arr[i];
            } else if (arr[i] > LS[count-1]) {
                LS[count++] = arr[i];
            } else {
                LS[BS(arr,0,count-1,arr[i])] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

So can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong.Thanks in advance.

Comment: first input will be number of integers in the array and in the next line, we will give the sequence of integers.

Comment: in a subsequence, you are not allowed to change the order. so `LS[0] = arr[i];` does not work, because it is possible that `LS[1] ` is `arr[i-1]`

Comment: Why not print out the found sequence, it might help see if that extra one is from the start or end, or a repeat.

Comment: no I am not changing the order,my algorithm is that I will take the next element in the array and compare it with the first element,if it is the smallest,I will replace the element,if the end of the LS is smaller than the current element,I will append to the end of the array else I will do a binary search to find out the correct position of the element

Comment: this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Efficient_algorithms is the algorithm for what you are trying to do. It does not look like what you are doing.

Comment: yes you are changing the order. If the array is `2, 3, 1`, the LS after 3 iterations is `1, 3`

Comment: yeah you are right but I am doing this program to find the length,not the actual sequence.And I am getting the right output for the {2,3,1} array i.e. 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug here:
`LS[BS(arr,0,count-1,arr[i])] = arr[i];`should be
`LS[BS(LS,0,count-1,arr[i])] = arr[i];` instead, because we need to update the array with the smallest value for each length of an increasing sub sequence (that is, `LS`), not the original one. 
With this change, it works properly on your test case (I haven't tested it on anything else, but the algorithm looks correct to me now).

Comment: Yeah you are right.my mistake.its working fine now.Thanks for your help :).